# Why is the d3.js group element hopping at first drag?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create a d3-group with some shapes (like rect, circle,...) in it and it has to be draggable. The dragging works, but when the dragging starts, the shape is "hopping". I know I need something like `.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)`. But then I get an error, that "d" is undefined. How can I fix the "hopping"?
Here is a very simple code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%");

rectGroup();

function rectGroup() {
var group = svg.append('g')
    .attr("class", "group")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("drag", dragged));

group.append("rect")
    .data([{ x: 200, y: 200, width: 100 , height: 100}])
    .attr('class', 'rect')
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height; });
}

function dragged(d) {
d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("x", d3.event.x)
d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("y", d3.event.y)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `drag` on the groups. However, you're using the `x` and `y` properties of the rectangles in the `dragged` function.

You have to decide which one are you calling `drag` upon, the rectangle or the group, and after this decision you have to change your code accordingly.

For instance, if you want to keep the drag on the group, you'll have to use `translate`:

```
function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + 
    "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")")
}
```

After setting the `x` and `y` data for the group.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");

rectGroup();

function rectGroup() {
  var group = svg.append('g')
    .datum({
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    })
    .attr("class", "group")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("drag", dragged));

  group.append("rect")
    .data([{
      x: 200,
      y: 200,
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }])
    .attr('class', 'rect')
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.width;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d.height;
    });
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo Furtado, I'm not fully understanding it, but it works. So I need to look deeper into "translate". Tanks!